# How to properly define an extension function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a `class` like this:

```js
export default class UserDto {
    email: string;
    permissions: string[];
    roles: string[];
}
```

and a `d.ts` file that defines `toUser`:

```js
declare global {
    class UserDto {
        toUser(): User;
    }
}
```

and the function declaration in a regular `ts` file:

```js
import User from "types/User";
import Activity from "types/Activity";
import Role from "types/Role";
import UserDto from "types/UserDto";

UserDto.prototype.toUser() = function (): User {
    return {
        email: this.email,
        permissions: new Set(this.permissions.map((p) => Activity[p])),
        roles: new Set(this.roles.map((r) => Role[r])),
    };
};
```

My problem is that when I try to use this extension it doesn't work (and VS Code doesn't recognize it either):

```js
import Role from "types/Role";
import User from "types/User";
import UserDto from "types/UserDto";
import Activity from "types/Activity";
import toUser from "extensions/UserDtoExtensions";

import users from "data/users.json";
import roles from "data/roles.json";

export default function findUser(email: string): User {
    const userDto: UserDto = users[email];
    if (userDto) {
        return userDto.toUser();
    } else {
        return {
            email: "anon@anon.com",
            permissions: new Set(
                roles.Anonymous.permissions.map((p) => Activity[p])
            ),
            roles: new Set([Role.Anonymous]),
        };
    }
}
```

I get

> TypeError: userDto.toUser is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

What's also interesting is that in the file where I augment the `prototype` VS Code also says

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

1. In [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

> **Default exports also cannot be augmented**, only named exports (since you need to augment an export by its exported name, and default is a reserved word - see #14080 for details)

2. `declare module "types/UserDto"`, not `declare global`.
3. `import "extensions/UserDtoExtensions"`, without `toUser from`.

I *think* those should be all the required changes.